# Calling private instance variable from other applcation whose getter setter not avaliable

Tags: java, reflection

I am reading string xml data from **other application** in my project using JAXB.

They have provided their appdata.jar. (I dont have control on their classes).
They have MessgeBody. In MessageBody they have defined **one** private instance variable without getter and setter. And because of this I am not able to obtain instance of perticular class.Remaining fields with getter n setter are accessible.
I tried Java reflection , it is not working.
Here is my code -

```
Class Test{

public void parseXMLStr(){
 String xmlStr="<xml><first></first><second></second><third></third></xml>"

 //I am able to get values of first and second as getter and setter defined.  
   First f =getMessageBody().getFirst();
   f.dosomething()..  //working
   Second s =getMessageBody().getSecond();
   s.dosomething()...//working
}
```

appdata.jar(**other application**) contains MessageBody as,

```
 class MessageBody{
  private First first;//getter setter provided
  private Second second;//getter setter provided
  private Third third;//getter setter NOT Provided
}
```

How I can obtain Third class instance and access variables inside it.

I tried Java reflection as below but I am getting null pointer exception(although data is there )

```
   Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("third"); 
   f.setAccessible(true);
   Third t = (Third) f.get(obj); 
   t.getName();//here getting nullpointer exception
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code it works fine for me. I think your object  might have  null value for third. It could be that since getter and setter is missing your xml is not getting mapped to pojo properly b'cos many mapper uses setter to map the data to POJO. just debug once and check.

Comment: @Nawnit Sen , I tried with individual java programs and getting same null pointer exception. Can you share your code please.

Comment: i have tried exactly same thing that you are trying .i can't post that as answer can you please add what indivisual java program you have tried?

Comment: @Nawnit Sen , yes my individual java programs working now.Need to check application program which is almost same :(

Comment: Just debug it and see if value is present for third or not?